# How to use the newly created column in Derived Column Transformation again in the same Derived column transformation?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Suppose I created a column named 'Studata' in derived column where in expression is

right({someothercolname},4)

And in the same derived column , I created other column 'studata2' where in expression I wanted to give as left({Studata},1).
So this is throwing error because I cannot use the same column created in same derived column transformation.

So without an extra derived column ,can we achieve this within same derived column transformation?

Comment: Derived column is used to either generate a new column or update an existing one. The column is created after derived column activity. So, you cannot use the same column created in same derived column transformation It will create column with the name you gave but it will not be able to fetch the value in it. It will give you column not found error because it is not get created. to achieve your scenario, you have to use two derived column activities one after another.

Comment: Derived column can only fetch schema of incoming stream. not of itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Derived column transformation` fetches the schema on the incoming stream and only perform the expressions based on that column only.
- The columns which you create in `Derived column transformation` are accessible in next transformation only not in same `Derived column transformation`.
- I as it fetches the schema of previous stream only so it will throw **error as column not found**.

[image]

Work around is to use two `Derived column transformations` one after another as below:

[image]

[image]

**Output**

[image]